# При соприкосновении двух одинаковых объектов удалить только один

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру по типу Jelly Run 2048, У меня есть скрипт куба, в котором реализован метод onTriggerEnter, и при соприкосновении кубов уничтожаются оба куба.

как сделать, чтобы уничтожался только один куб?

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ECubePower Power;
    public Material[] Materials;

    private MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        _meshRenderer.material = Materials[(int)Power];
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Cube>(out Cube cube))
        {
            UpPower(cube.Power);
            Destroy(cube.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void UpPower(ECubePower PowerLevel)
    {
        Power += (int)PowerLevel;
    }

    public void DownPower(ECubePower PowerLevel)
    {
        Power -= (int)PowerLevel;
    }
}
```

```
public enum ECubePower
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
}
```

Comment: не надо править заголовок, галочка на ответе и так сама по себе означает, что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в перечисление нулевой элемент, назовем его например `Zero`

```
public enum ECubePower
{
    Zero,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
}
```

Тогда можно сделать так, что если `Power` куба равнялся `Zero`, то он самоуничтожался.

```
public void DownPower(ECubePower PowerLevel)
{
    Power -= (int)PowerLevel;
    if (Power == ECubePower.Zero)
       Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

А триггер реализовать как-то так

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (Power != ECubePower.Zero && other.TryGetComponent<Cube>(out Cube cube))
    {
        var power = cube.Power;
        UpPower(power);
        cube.DownPower(power);
    }
}
```

Comment: это не имеет смысла т.к этот метод вызовется для обоих кубов и ничего не поменяется

Comment: @Citrus вы попробовали? Ваш комментарий вызван невнимательностью.

Comment: да, только что попробовал

Comment: @Citrus `if (Power > 0` не забыли добавить? Быть может код не в точности скопировали и что-то упустили? Должно работать 100%, здесь нет сомнений. Либо покажите, что такое `ECubePower`, от этого черного ящика тоже что-то может зависеть.

Comment: Я все скопировал, не работает, т.к метод колизи вызывается у обоих кубов, они оба повышают себе мощь и уменьшают другому соответственно как была мощь допустим 2 так она и осталась у обоих

Comment: @Citrus не могут скрипты работать одновременно. Сначала отрабатывает один, потом другой. Система запуска кода в скриптах однопоточная. Да, они отработают в одном и том же кадре, но не одновременно. То есть сначала отработает один тригер и обнулит значение второго куба, а когда сработает второй триггер, значение куба уже будет 0 и условие `if (Power > 0` просто не выполнится. Либо вы что-то упустили, либо что-то не договариваете. Покажите, что такое `ECubePower`. Добавьте код в вопрос, вопрос можно редактировать.

Comment: понял вашу мысль но Power 0 означает 1 индекс перечисления, вот класс public enum ECubePower
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
}

Comment: @Citrus вот здесь собака и зарыта, добавьте в перечисление первым пунктом еще значение, которое будет одначать `0`, например `Zero`. И на него проверку проводите `if (Power != ECubePower.Zero` вместо `if (Power > 0`.

Comment: вот только что сам допер за минуту до вашего ответа, теперь все работает, спасибо

Comment: @Citrus подкорректировал ответ под реальность.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя кубы одинаковые, а должны быть технически разными. На тех кубах, что двигаются делай OnTriggerEnter, где будет вся логика обработки столкновения; а на неподвижных просто оставляй триггер, т. к. на них не должно быть никакой логики обработки столкновения.

Comment: просто планируется, что если мощь куба, который просто стоит меньше, чем  у игрока, то игрок будет его толкать, и куб, который толкает игрок сможет поднять свою мощь, если столкнется с таким же кубом как и он сам по мощи. Т.е. у всех кубов должен быть обработчик столкновения